# Route ports to instances using Amazon VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a simple VPC on Amazon EC2 with two instances: an SFTP server, and a web server. I want to route incoming traffic from the internet on port 22 to the SFTP server and ports 80 and 443 to the web server.

I'm having trouble finding exactly how to do this. It's extremely simple with all hardware routers I've ever used.

Can anyone point me to documentation/examples/or just tell me how to do it?

Edit:
I wasn't clear that I want remote hosts to be able to make a request to a single IP address, but on different ports, and have different ports routed to different instances; I already have my security groups set so I can accept traffic to the public IP addresses of each instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the steps you will need to follow to achieve your use case.

1. As you said both servers are in VPC you need to make sure they are
   in a Public Subnet with a internet gateway attached to it.(This can
   be achieved in Private subnet too but will become more complex
   process for you) For more information check this
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario1.html
2. EC2 Server 1 for SFTP you need to open SSH port 22 in the security group by adding your IP address or open to world rule. Then you can SFTP using your preferred SFTP client.
3. EC2 Server 2 for port 80 and 443. you need to add two rules in the security group for your instance. Check below screenshot. Once that is done you will be able to route http traffic through port 80 and 443.

More information on security groups is here.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

[image]

About your Edit. You have to run a instance in front of both the instance.

Add a HTTP proxy to  this new created instance. And then the port redirect should be achieved using IP Tables. Check this below IP tables config you need to add to that server. Let say your HTTP proxy server is Server 1. Port 22 server is Server 2 and Port 80 and 443 Server is Server 3. So Server 1 IP tables will have below rules.

```
    #!/bin/sh

    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

    iptables -F
    iptables -t nat -F
    iptables -X

    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <Server3-IP>:80

    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d <Server3-IP> --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source <Server1-IP>

    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination <Server2-IP>:80

    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d <Server2-IP> --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source <Server1-IP>

    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination <Server3-IP>:80

    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d <Server3-IP> --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source <Server1-IP>
```

Comment: I understand how I can set up the security groups to allow access to the individual public IP addresses of the instances. I want to be able to route a request to a single IP address (the IP address of my internet gateway?), say 1.2.3.4, but 1.2.3.4:22 goes to one instance, 1.2.3.4:80 goes to the other.

Comment: If you want them to use the same DNS name, you'll need to set up an instance running haproxy or squid or the like to route the traffic to the desired backend instance according to port.

Comment: This answer does not solve the OP's desired use-case of having a single IP address for all 3 ports.

Comment: Seems strange to me that amazon's virtual router doesn't do what seems to be the simplest possible use case for a router.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Amazon Elastic Load Balancers have a new "Application Load Balancer" mode which supports routing requests to different EC2 instances based on things such as the HTTP path, **and port**.

To set this up, do the following:

1. Create a new ELB, using the new "Application Load Balancer" mode.
2. Create one target group for port 22.
3. Add your EC2 instances that will be the SSH targets to this target group.
4. Create another target group for ports 80 and 443.
5. Add your EC2 instances that will be the HTTP/HTTPs targets  to this target group.

Using this system, SSH requests to the ELB will be forwarded to the SSH instance, and HTTP/HTTPs requests to the ELB will be forwarded to the web servers

Comment: thanks. I'll mark this as the answer since it doesn't require firing up an additional instance

Comment: @juacala Using this application load balancer you cannot send a SSH request through that load balancer it is only for HTTP and HTTPS requests. And also you will not be able to use a single IP address as Load Blancers IP address are not static they are dynamic.

Comment: ELB (and now ALB) is not just for HTTP and HTTPS connections. ELB can handle any TCP/IP connection (hence the TCP listener). Many people use it for SSH. And while it may not be using a single static IP address, it does use a single CNAMEable or ALIASable endpoint.

Comment: My mistake. The new Application Load Balancer does not support TCP listeners at the moment. @error2007s is correct, it only supports HTTP and HTTPS right now. I would imagine it would be added at some point in the future.